# Express get session data without req

Tags: session, express

I am trying to test whether or not passportjs is generating the correct session data. Is there anyway to get the session data without calling res.session inside a route? ie.

```
router.post("/", function(req,res){
createSessionVariable()
console.log(session.newVariable();
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use `req.session`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per robertklep's comment

req.session is the answer. I just assumed that the req variable was not dynamic, but apparently it is.

Thanks robert.